# How to prevent fully qualified names in Java code

Tags: java, checkstyle, intellij-14

Is it possible to check with checkstyle if a java project is using fully qualified names in the code. We want to prevent code like

```
if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank(name)) { 
 ....
 ....
}
```

and want to enforce that packages are instead imported instead.

Are there are other tools that can help us accomplish it?

Comment: What would you expect from the tool if there are class name conflicts?

Comment: You can check it with the import control rule. Then configure the Maven Checkstyle plugin so any violations will not allow the build...?

Comment: Interesting question. But are you sure you would want to enable this? I've needed to use fully qualified names at times when I'm dealing with legacy code, and somebody has made use of a *custom* `StringUtils` class. Given that class' inadequacy, I end up using the Apache Commons `StringUtils` in that class, while the import is already used on the custom `StringUtils`, and hence my need for it.

Comment: @JonathanThoms We are also dealing with legacy code and had taken great care to remove the kind of custom classes that you describe. We need a check as part of our build process so that such fully qualified names are no more added to the code.

Comment: @varevarao We don't want our code to have exactly similar class names that are required to be used in the same .java file. If such a case does arrive the tool can provide a means to specify exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Checkstyle cannot do this. However, there is a PMD rule called [UnnecessaryFullyQualifiedName](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/rules/java/imports.html#UnnecessaryFullyQualifiedName) which may be worth a look. IntelliJ plugins for PMD exist, for example [QAPlug PMD](http://qaplug.com/), which is free to download.

Be prepared to see a lot of false positives though. For example, two classes which share the same simple name cannot be referenced without a fully qualified class name (e.g. `foo.A` and `bar.A`). Might also be that PMD actually checks for this case, it may be worth a try.

Comment: The PMD check only warns if there is already an imported form of the class (I think it compares the imports and fully qualified names in code), so there's not much false positives, but it won't warn if the fully qualified class isn't listed in the imports yet. A case sensitive regex search like [a-z]+[.][a-z]+[.][A-Z] can help to catch some of the non-imported ones, but this one will definitely have false positives :)

Answer (score 2):

FTR I've just raised https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/issues/462 about potentially adding this to Checkstyle some time .. contributions welcome! ;-)

Comment: I'd upvote anything by the creator of the mariadb java wrapper :)